# Understanding Motorola ColdFire instructions.

Tags: ida, motorola

I have a coldfire sequence from IDAPro that looks like this:

```
sub_29be8:

var_8 = -8
var_2 = -2
arg_0 = 8
arg_6 = $E

link a6, #-4;  
move.l a2, -(sp)
movea.l arg_0(a6),a2
tst.w arg_6(a6)
bne.s loc_29c00
bset #5, $1e(a2)
bra.s loc_29c14

....
```

In the documentation [here](http://www.depeca.uah.es/depeca/repositorio/asignaturas/20602/InstructionSet.pdf), I'm having some issues with understanding what exactly the documentation is saying.

`LINK Ay,#<displacement> W 
SP – 4→SP; //subtract SP by 4 and set into SP
Ay → (SP); //set address pointed to in Ay and set into value of SP
SP→Ay, SP + dn → SP  //set SP into Ay, add the offset specified by <displacement> and set into SP`

Are ALL of these steps executed for the `LINK` instruction, or are these the possibilities based on some processor states that I haven't found out about yet?  (This appears to be setting up the stack for a function call.)

The next question I have about the sequence is the second instruction, `move.l a2, -(sp)`

This appears to be moving a `longword` from a2 into the stack pointer, HOWEVER the negation looks odd to me.  It appears to be "move address in a2 into SP and then multiply its value by -1" but I could also see the parenthesis being used as specifying an order of operations to be applied to the address.

Comment: Your second question is explained in (uh) about *any* 68K documentation: it's just a pre-decrement. If you are familiar with x86 code: it's a push, but to *any* A-register, and 'you' need to decrement the address yourself, or it'll just store the new value.

Comment: @Jongware, I'm using the ColdFire User Manual, and the only reference to "predecrement" in the entire 700+ pages was a description of the algorithm used by the MASK instruction.  I had to dig up a different "programmer's reference" to get more detail.

Comment: Gave me the answer to `LINK` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the `LINK` question was provided on page 119 [here](http://www.freescale.com/files/dsp/doc/ref_manual/CFPRM.pdf).

Pre/Post decrement operations are described on page 44.